# PIXI remove spriteSheet Texture cache

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, pixi.js

I have loaded spriteSheetFrame using json.

```
const loader = new PIXI.loaders.Loader();
loader.add('bunny', 'data/bunny.png')
      .add('spaceship', 'assets/spritesheet.json');
loader.load((loader, resources) => {

});
```

I want to remove all the TextureCache which was loaded using this spritesheet.json only.

I have tried.

```
PIXI.Texture.removeFromCache("spaceship");
PIXI.Texture.removeTextureFromCache("spaceship");
```

But in PIXI.TextureCache names of all the spriteFrame were included there.
And still i am able to use image form frame. Using this.

```
var bgSprite2 = PIXI.Sprite.fromFrame("ship1");
bgSprite2.anchor.set(0.5, 0.5);
var pos = {x: 300, y: 200};
bgSprite2.position.set(pos.x, pos.y);
stage.addChild(bgSprite2);
```

I want to remove all the entries of spriteFrame in TextureCache and i want to load new set of spriteFrame.

I am doing this because i have spritesheet animations of two diffrent spaceship but the individual symbol name of both spaceship are same.

Comment: If the spritesheets are identical json-data-wise (just images are different), then how about if you just change / swap the texture. I am just wondering why you have 2 identical and you want to remove the first and use the second.

Answer (score 0):

I would agree with Hachi that you could gain some performance from just replacing the texture rather than destroying and re-creating over and over. Caching could be the answer.

You could then eventually call destroy when your done with them to make sure there is nothing lingering around.